# CSS or Javascript files don't work my create-react-app dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I have my app created in create-react-app and I have a dynamic path that creates a document by id, the problem is that when I reload the page in the dynamic path created by that it does not load the css or the external javascript including only the HTML
Please if someone can help me I would appreciate it a lot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qigoz.png)

When reloading the dynamic route page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPbGX.png)

Loading fonts, css and js in the public / index.html folder of react
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaVUs.png)

---

As I told you, everything works perfectly when I enter the page from the beginning "/" but when I reload the page in the dynamic paths "/ document / 5141" the css or js does not work
If the same thing happened to someone, I would appreciate it if you share the solution
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste your code, not images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add your scripts under public folder if not right now and refer it as mentioned below.

From react documentation ,

If you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by webpack. Instead it will be copied into the build folder untouched. To reference assets in the public folder, you need to use an environment variable called PUBLIC_URL.

Inside index.html, you can use it like this:

`<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`

Only files inside the public folder will be accessible by %PUBLIC_URL% prefix. If you need to use a file from src or node_modules, you’ll have to copy it there to explicitly specify your intention to make this file a part of the build.